# ASP.NET, SQL Server 2008 R2, System.OverflowException

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to INSERT a record in an SQL Server 2008 R2 table using a Stored Procedure. I am "trying" to write a generic class for database access.

Here's the code in .VB file:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If PreviousPage IsNot Nothing AndAlso PreviousPage.IsCrossPagePostBack Then
        Dim params(5) As SqlParameter
        params(0) = New SqlParameter("@Name", PreviousPage.Name.Text)
        params(1) = New SqlParameter("@Qualification", PreviousPage.Qualification.Text)
        params(2) = New SqlParameter("@ContactNo", PreviousPage.ContactNo.Text)
        params(3) = New SqlParameter("@Expertise", PreviousPage.Expertise.Text)
        params(4) = New SqlParameter("@Comments", PreviousPage.Comments.Text)
        params(5) = New SqlParameter("@Affiliation", PreviousPage.Affiliation.Text)
        DAL.DoInsertSP(params)
    End If
End Sub
```

Here's the code for DAL.DoInsertSP():

```
Public Shared Function DoInsertSP(ByRef params As Array) As Byte
    Dim result As Byte = 0
    CreateConnection()
    cmd = New SqlCommand("sp_InsertExpert", conn)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(params)
    Try
        result = CByte(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery())
    Catch ex As Exception
        conn.Dispose()
    End Try
    Return result
End Function
```

The code is throwing an **System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.**

Here's the script for the proc **sp_InsertExpert**

```
USE [dbherpes]
```

GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_InsertExpert]
    @Name             nvarchar(30) = null,
    @Qualification  nvarchar(40) = null,
    @ContactNo      nvarchar(13) = null,
    @Expertise      nvarchar(30) = null,
    @Comments       nvarchar(100) = null,
    @Affiliation    nvarchar(50) = null
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO Expert (Name, Qualification, ContactNo, Expertise, Comments, Affiliation) VALUES (@Name, @Qualification, @ContactNo, @Expertise, @Comments, @Affiliation)
END

Here's the structure of the table:

[image]

How can I correct this please?

**UPDATE**

I have set ID column's Identity Specification = 'Yes', Identity Increment = 1, Indentity Seed = 1

Comment: shouldn't your `ID` be an int?

Comment: Cut out .NET all together and run sp_InsertExpert from SQL Managment Studio with the same data and what do you get?

Answer (score 1):

Do you not have the line number in which the exception is occuring?

By looking at your code:

> ExecuteNonQuery

returns an INT as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx

I would suggest not converting the output to a byte but rather comparing cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() to a value, such as `> 0`

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number
>   of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number
>   of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return
>   value is also -1.

Comment: The solution proposed by Daniel A. White works for me. After applying the fix posted by him, I opened the table in Management Studio and found the "rows I thought were not not being stored in database" were also there along the rows that were inserted after the fix.